# Using custom or different column other than rowtime column as timestamp column in KSQL while doing joins

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

Hi i am trying out KSQL and found that most of the documentation provides example of direct joins with kstream or ktable. Lets say i have 2 streams already created by team X and i can't change it or recreate new streams and also want to use existing stream. Here by default rowtime is consider for timestamp column while joining. Is there any way to specify other than rowtime column as timestamp column in existing streams and consider its time windows for joining in KSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify any valid column using the `WITH (TIMESTAMP='column_name')` syntax. For example:

```
CREATE STREAM ORDERS (ORDER_ID INT, 
                      CUSTOMER_ID INT, 
                      ORDER_TS VARCHAR, 
                      ORDER_TOTAL_USD DOUBLE, 
                      MAKE VARCHAR) 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='orders', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', 
        TIMESTAMP='ORDER_TS', TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ssX');
```

This will use the `ORDER_TS` column as the timestamp in any time-related KSQL operations (i.e. windowed joins and aggregations). You can validate this by comparing the `ROWTIME` value to the `ORDER_TS` and observe that they are the same.

References:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql (section *Managing message timestamps in KSQL*)
- https://rmoff.net/2019/03/28/exploring-ksql-stream-stream-joins/

Comment: HI robin thanks for your reply. I was aware about above method to create timestamp column during creation of streams. My question is specifying timestamp column during join. Lets say i have 2 existing streams and they are already created by team x with only rowtime as timestamp. Now i would like to use some different column from those existing streams as timestamp during join. Also edited question for more clarity.